# While passing an enum in a REST controller, I'm getting java.lang.IllegalArgumentException whereas I'm using enum as string

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Controller:-

```
@RequestMapping(value="/CreateMovie", method= RequestMethod.POST)
    public HttpStatus createMovie(@RequestBody JSONObject object) {
        Movie movie =new Movie(object.optString("name"),
                    MovieType.valueOf(object.optString("type")),
                    new Date(object.optString("releasedate")),
                    Integer.parseInt(object.optString("time")), 
                    Genre.valueOf(object.optString("genre")));
            //object.

    repository.save(movie);

    return HttpStatus.OK;

}
```

Entity is as follows:-

```
@Entity(name="Movie")
public class Movie {


    public Movie()
    {

    }
    public Movie(String name,MovieType type,Date releasedate,
          int movie_length, Genre genre)
    {
        this.name=name;
        this.type=type;
        this.releasedate=releasedate;
        this.movie_length=movie_length;
        this.genre=genre;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="Id")
    private long id;

    @Column(name="movie_name")
    @NotNull
    String name;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    //@NotNull
    MovieType type;
    @Column(name="release_date")
    @JsonFormat(shape=STRING, pattern="dd-MM-yyyy")
    //@NotNull
    Date releasedate;
    @Column(name="movie_length")
    //@NotNull
    int movie_length;
    @Column(name="like_percentage")
    float likepercentage;
    @Column(name="no_of_reactions")
    float no_of_reactions;
    @Column(name="avg_rating")
    float avg_rating;
    @Column(name="no_of_reviews")
    int no_of_reviews;
    @Column(name="director")
    @NotNull
    String director;
    @Transient
    List<String> cities;
    @Transient
    List<String> cast;
```

Enum is as follows:-

```
public enum MovieType {

    Hindi("Hindi"),
    English("English"),
    Telugu("Telugu"),
    Malyalam("Malyalam"),
    Kannada("Kannnada");

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    MovieType(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


}
```

Stack Trace is as below:-

Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant com.example.Model.MovieType.] with root cause

Comment: It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details. And submit your code in the right way.

Comment: You need to paste your code correctyl. Your entity is not seems correct. Also please share what is your request contains and stacktrace.

Comment: @EmreSavcı Can you please check now? Request is:-{
"name":"BodyGuard",
"type":"English",
"releasedate":"26/07/2015",
"time":"160",
"genre":"Drama"
}

Comment: If you're using Spring, don't use `JSONObject` as your controller parameter; pass a `Movie` or a non-entity `MovieDto` object, and Spring will copy all of the properties onto it automatically. (And your JPA entity can't be a Spring bean; remove the `@Component` and `@Bean` from it.)

Comment: @chrylis I want to know how can I use enum if I prefer to choose JSONObject as the request parameter.

Comment: There is no special way to use the enum: as long as it is part of the object you pass (Movie)... check my code sample - it works.

Comment: @RaviSinghShekhawat You can't if you're doing all of this manually. Stop doing it manually and let Spring do it for you, and it will automatically map the enum.

Answer (score 0):

**This is how your controller should look like** **(the following code works):**

```
@GetMapping(path = "/movies")
public Movie getMovie() {
    Movie movie = new Movie("name", MovieType.English, new Date(), 1, Genre.Action);
    return movie;
}

@PostMapping(path = "/movies")
public HttpStatus createMovie(@RequestBody Movie movie) {
    repository.save(movie);
    return HttpStatus.OK;
}
```

Movie object:

```
public class Movie {

    public String name;
    public Date releasedate;
    public MovieType type;
    public int movie_length;
    public Genre genre;

    public Movie() {}

    public Movie(String name, MovieType type, Date releasedate, int movie_length, Genre genre) {
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
        this.releasedate = releasedate;
        this.movie_length = movie_length;
        this.genre = genre;
    }
}
```

MovieType:

```
public enum MovieType {
    Hindi("Hindi"), English("English"), Telugu("Telugu"), Malyalam("Malyalam"), Kannada("Kannnada");

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    MovieType(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Genre:

```
public enum Genre {
    Daram("Drama"), Action("Action");

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    Genre(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

**Notes:**

- Pass Movie as an object - don't use JsonObject to parse a json
- Use the url conventions as stated above (i.e. movies for both GET and POST)
- GET the movie object with **getMovie()** and use it's template to the send a similar object to **createMovie()** with POST.
- Use [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) or any other Rest client to test your code

**Sample POST request:**

```
{
    "name": "name",
    "releasedate": "2018-12-23T10:01:47.056+0000",
    "type": "English",
    "movie_length": 1,
    "genre": "Action"
}
```

Make sure you send the request body as JSON:
[image]

Goodluck

Comment: Nope that does't solve my problem. My Postman request is as below:- {
"name":"BodyGuard",
"type":"English",
"releasedate":"26-10-2015",
"time":"160",
"genre":"Drama"
}. If I need to use only setter, how do I do it?

Comment: https://www.devglan.com/spring-boot/enums-as-request-parameters-in-spring-boot-rest. I think there are some particular ways to embed enum in spring boot requests.

Comment: ok, I edited my answer to include the Genre as well... you can also check my POST sample - this will return HttpStatus.OK... as you can see, the enums are passed as Strings.

Comment: But why we are hardcoding values English in the movietype and action in the Genre. Another doubt is why do we need get request point for using post request in the first place?

Comment: The hardcoded String is being 'translated' by the JSON Mapper to a valid enum object (so you don't have to worry about it); the GET request is optional - I usually use it since it helps to understand how the object should look like in JSON format.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this in two ways, the first way you can remove the `name` field in your `MovieType` enum. Such Enum contains only values, and Spring JPA creates a record for you the database with the corresponding value of your Enum. The second way is to tell him to find the Enum type with the corresponding Enum name when creating a Spring JPA object.

For the first way, just update your MovieType Enum field as follows:

```
public enum MovieType {

    Hindi,
    English,
    Telugu,
    Malyalam,
    Kannada;
}
```

For the second way, update `MovieType` Enum as follows,

```
public enum MovieType {

    Hindi("Hindi"),
    English("English"),
    Telugu("Telugu"),
    Malyalam("Malyalam"),
    Kannada("Kannada");

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    MovieType(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public static MovieType of(String name) {
        return Stream.of(MovieType.values())
          .filter(mt -> mt.getName().equals(name))
          .findFirst()
          .orElseThrow(IllegalArgumentException::new);
    }
}
```

And you can use it in this way:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/CreateMovie", method= RequestMethod.POST)
public HttpStatus createMovie(@RequestBody JSONObject object) {
    Movie movie =new Movie(object.optString("name"),
                MovieType.of(object.optString("type")),
                new Date(object.optString("releasedate")),
                Integer.parseInt(object.optString("time")), 
                Genre.valueOf(object.optString("genre")));
        //object.

    repository.save(movie);

    return HttpStatus.OK;

}
```